# jquery(html, attributes) in attributes calling function off of

Tags: jquery

At http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes there is a note that says:

As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter

I'm guessing that a function can be called multiple times by some means but the example given shows the on() method invoked once and doesn't show multiple events. Can someone provide or point me to a more complex example?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I saw, this is only another form of creating elements and attaching events.

For instance, this means that you can do the following, passing all attributes as the second parameter:

```
$("<p></p>", {
  "class": "my-class",
  "text": "This is a test",
    click: function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
     $(this).css('color', 'red');
    },
    mouseout: function() {
     $(this).css('color', 'green');   
    }
}).appendTo( "body" );
```

This is just another way of doing this:

```
$("<p></p>")
  .addClass("my-class")
  .text("This is a test too")
  .click(function() { $(this).css('color', 'blue'); })
  .mouseenter(function() { $(this).css('color', 'red'); })
  .mouseout(function() { $(this).css('color', 'green'); })
  .appendTo( "body" );
```

The page says: "While the second argument is convenient, its flexibility can lead to unintended consequences (e.g. $( "", {size: "4"} ) calling the .size() method instead of setting the size attribute)."

It's nice to know different forms of doing the same thing, but I'll continue using the second one. :)

JSFiddle with the examples above: http://jsfiddle.net/m4f415dt/